# proj4js: calculate meridian convergence

Tags: coordinate-system, proj4js, convergence

Given a projection and coordinates of a single point, how do I calculate the meridian convergence at that point?

Is it even possible? I'm unable to find anything useful using Google.

If it is not possible, is there a generic way this can be done in JavaScript? I need to support different projections, so a single hard-coded formula will not do.